# Custom allocator fails for std::map

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl, g++

I'm trying to use custom allocator with C++ STL containers, and it works with vector, but fails with map. Some strange error regarding `mmap_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, int> > >` and not using `mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >` as I was expecting

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/map:60,
                 from 4.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function ‘_Alloc std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::get_allocator() const [with _Key = int, _Val = std::pair<const int, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:383:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Key = int, _Val = std::pair<const int, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:972:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Key = int, _Val = std::pair<const int, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:614:   instantiated from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::~_Rb_tree() [with _Key = int, _Val = std::pair<const int, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:87:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:354: error: no matching function for call to ‘mmap_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >::mmap_allocator(const mmap_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, int> > >&)’
4.cpp:37: note: candidates are: mmap_allocator<T>::mmap_allocator(const mmap_allocator<T>&) [with T = std::pair<const int, int>]
4.cpp:36: note:                 mmap_allocator<T>::mmap_allocator() [with T = std::pair<const int, int>]
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t alloc;

        template <typename T>
        class mmap_allocator: public std::allocator<T>
        {
public:
                typedef size_t size_type;
                typedef T* pointer;
                typedef const T* const_pointer;

                template<typename _Tp1>
                struct rebind
                {
                        typedef mmap_allocator<_Tp1> other;
                };

                pointer allocate(size_type n, const void *hint=0)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Alloc %d bytes.\n", n);
                        alloc += n;
                        return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
                }

                void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Dealloc %d bytes (%p).\n", n, p);
                        alloc -= n;
                        return std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n);
                }

                mmap_allocator() throw(): std::allocator<T>() { fprintf(stderr, "Hello allocator!\n"); }
                mmap_allocator(const mmap_allocator &a) throw(): std::allocator<T>(a) { }
                ~mmap_allocator() throw() { }
        };

int main(){

std::vector<int, mmap_allocator<int> > int_vec(1024, 0, mmap_allocator<int>());
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>,  mmap_allocator<std::pair<int,int> > >  x;
x[1] = 2;
printf("s=%lu\n", alloc);
return 0;
}
```

Linux, gcc 4.4.6.

Comment: I met the same issue, have you found what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried fixing it but it seems you haven't defined a constructor which takes an allocator instantiation with a different template argument. That is, you are missing something like

```
template <typename T>
    template <typename O>
mmap_allocator<T>::mmap_allocator(mmap_allocator<O> const& other) {
    ...
}
```

From the looks of it, the error stems from trying to construct an allocator type obtained from `rebind` with some other allocator.